# configure error when trying to build OpenSSL on CentOS

Tags: compiling, openssl

I have a Centos 5.7 operating system box and I have installed OpenSSL 1.0.1h successfully. but when I am upgrading OpenSSH I am getting the below error message while running ./configure. Kindly help me on this and let me know if you have any questions.

```
checking whether snprintf correctly terminates long strings... yes
checking whether snprintf can declare const char *fmt... yes
checking whether system supports SO_PEERCRED getsockopt... yes
checking for (overly) strict mkstemp... yes
checking if openpty correctly handles controlling tty... yes
checking whether getpgrp requires zero arguments... yes
checking OpenSSL header version... 1000108f (OpenSSL 1.0.1h 5 Jun 2014)
checking OpenSSL library version... 90802f (OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008)
checking whether OpenSSL's headers match the library... no
configure: error: Your OpenSSL headers do not match your
library. Check config.log for details.
If you are sure your installation is consistent, you can disable the check
by running "./configure --without-openssl-header-check".
Also see contrib/findssl.sh for help identifying header/library mismatches.
```

Comment: What happens if you follow the actions the configure script suggests?

Answer (score 1):

> ... i have installed OpenSSL 1.0.1h ...

Yes, but only the header version. Your library is still `0.9.8e-fips-rhel5` and not `1.0.1h` like your header. You need to install the matching library for your header.
Looks Like you installed `OpenSSL 1.0.1h` manually while `0.9.8e-fips-rhel5` seems to be a rhel version. The rhel-version probably was installed via package-management. Maybe you just need to uninstall the `0.9.8e` via `yum remove openssl-libs`. Afterwards check if your `OpenSSL 1.0.1h` libraries are detected (i assume you installed header + lib). If not, install `OpenSSL 1.0.1h`-libs (again).